# Vue + Vitest + Vute/test-utils: My tests can't find an element without two `await`s

Tags: testing, frontend, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have an autocomplete searcher in my signup form with unit tests for this component. One of my tests is not passing without I add two `await`s in the test.

This is what the component code boils down to:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="state.searchText" />
  <p v-if="state.noResults" data-testid="no-results">No results</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, watch } from "vue";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

import { searchCities } from "../services/searchCities";

const state = reactive({
  searchText: "",
  noResults: false,
});

const searchServerForCities = debounce(async () => {
  const cities = await searchCities(state.searchText);
  // state.cities = cities;

  state.noResults = cities.length === 0;
}, 300);

watch(
  () => state.searchText,
  () => {
    searchServerForCities.cancel();
    state.noResults = false;

    searchServerForCities();
  }
);
</script>
```

And this is the test code:

```
import { vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import CitiesSearch from '../Books.vue'

import * as citiesService from '../../services/searchCities'

test('Books show `No Results` when API returns no result', async () => {
    vi.useFakeTimers()

    vi.spyOn(citiesService, 'searchCities').mockReturnValue([])

    const wrapper = mount(CitiesSearch)
    const input = wrapper.find(`input`)
    await input.setValue('a-city-that-does-not-exist')

    vi.advanceTimersByTime(500)

    // You may be wondering why I did put two await console.logs here!
    // The answer is pretty simple: I don't know!
    // But you dare to touch it, and tests will fail :))
    await (() => { })
    await (() => { })

    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-testid="no-results"]`).element).toBeTruthy()

    vi.restoreAllMocks();
})
```

And this is the CodeSandbox Cloud link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nervous-dawn-jxw0yc (try running `npm test` and see the tests pass.

The test passes and all is good, except there are two `await (() => {})` in the code, and if I remove them, it will fail.

My question is:

1. What is the best practice here? What was I doing wrong when I used two `await` on empty functions? Why couldn't I use a better way of mocking timers in `vitest` or use `Vue`'s `nextTick` as I normally would?
2. What are those 2 `await`s really skipping? Is it Vue's lifecycles? Service call `await`? Or the debounce? or the watch?

Thanks

I actually tried using `nextTick` without `await`, I tried using `vi.runAllTimers()` which didn't work. I tried using `await` on these, but it requires exactly two `await`s to pass the test. And I don't see why doing two `await nextTick()`s are better than two `await (() => {})` or `await console.log()`s.